# C++/SFML Positioning Sprite Issue

Tags: c++, sfml

I have a class named 'Player' where I handle movements, level ups etc in a game I am attempting to create. In the main loop in the main source file I have the keyboard events (Left/Right.) I want the movements to be able to know when your character is venturing past where it's allowed. To answer the problem I placed two if statements.

I am only having issues with this if statement:

```
else if (sf::Keyboard::IsKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right)) {
            if (Player.getX() > 1279) {
                Player.move(640,0);
            }
            Player.move(0.1,0);
        }
```

No compiling issues. The only issue is, unlike the other if statement, this one doesn't return the sprite to the wanted position. If I lower the if statement to something like 1000, the sprite disappears from the screen.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Player.move(640,0);
```

Your moving your player 640 pixel on the X-axis. This means that when the player gets to `x > 1279`, i.e. at the right end of your world, you move the player further to the right. So it disappears.

You might want to use `setPosition` instead of `move` here, or simply don't move the player, etc...